# paramiko : invoke ssh shell from a custom module

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I was wondering if there is way to pass the channel object from one program (imported as python module) to be used in another. For example - I have following program that I import into another program using `c = Connect(host,user,pwd)` and then invoke ssh shell on this.

Connect.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
import logging
import time

class Connect:
    def __init__(self,host,user,pwd):

        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.pwd = pwd
        port = 22   
        logfile = 'log.txt'
        logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile,level=logging.INFO)

        try:
            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.ssh.connect(host,port,username=self.user,password=self.pwd,allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
            logging.info('Connected to %r host' % host)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info('Exception caught : %r' % str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, it was simple ..

```
chan = c.ssh.invoke_shell()
```

this does the job. Now I dont need to write the Connect related script in my programs any more.